# Scaling image cover div and preserving aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I am attempting to have an image inside of a wrapper, and want the image to grow/shrink with the browser window. The image is **not** a background image, but an inline `<img>` element.

What I have is working, but I can only get it to force 100% height- sometimes the width comes up short. I want to force the image to be 100% of the width even if it's larger than the image itself (the image will just be distorted/zoomed in), and always center the image. So, no matter what, the image will take up the entire wrapper, zooming the image in if necessary, and will grow/contract with the browser window.

(You can see it better by opening the snippet in a full window)

```css
ul.archive-list > li {
  display: block;
}
ul.archive-list > li {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
ul.archive-list .archive-img-wrap {
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}
ul.archive-list img.archive-img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}
ul.archive-list h1.archive-title {
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #535353;
}
```

```html
<ul class="archive-list">
  <li>
    <article>
      <a href="#article" title="Article Title">
        <span class="archive-img-wrap"><img class="archive-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/2MAsv6e.jpg" alt="Article Title" /></span>
        <h1 class="archive-title">The Amazing Article Title is Shown Here</h1>
      </a>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article>
      <a href="#article" title="Article Title">
        <span class="archive-img-wrap"><img class="archive-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/2MAsv6e.jpg" alt="Article Title" /></span>
        <h1 class="archive-title">The Amazing Article Title is Shown Here</h1>
      </a>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article>
      <a href="#article" title="Article Title">
        <span class="archive-img-wrap"><img class="archive-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/2MAsv6e.jpg" alt="Article Title" /></span>
        <h1 class="archive-title">The Amazing Article Title is Shown Here</h1>
      </a>
    </article>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`object-fit`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit), just be aware that no support in IE and Edge currently.

```
img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8kkruva/)**

---

Javascript polyfills:

- https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit
- https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images
- https://github.com/tonipinel/object-fit-polyfill
- https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3#.be199342j

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS as you're using right now actually does the trick. The problem is that the height of your image is being restricted by `ul.archive-list .archive-img-wrap`.

If you remove `height: 200px;` from this class, your image will scale whilst preserving it's aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes, but I WANT the height to be 200px.

Answer (score 0):

`span` do not need to be a `flex` container, you can make it a `table-cell` like container and use `vertical-align` and `text-align`.

image might need also `max-width:100%;` unless you want it to overflow ,then `max-height` and `max-width` can be tutn into `min-height` and `min-width` .

```css
ul.archive-list > li {
  display: block;
}
ul.archive-list > li {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
ul.archive-list .archive-img-wrap {
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: red;
}
ul.archive-list img.archive-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
ul.archive-list h1.archive-title {
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #535353;
}
```

```html
<ul class="archive-list">
  <li>
    <article>
      <a href="#article" title="Article Title">
        <span class="archive-img-wrap"><img class="archive-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/2MAsv6e.jpg" alt="Article Title" /></span>
        <h1 class="archive-title">The Amazing Article Title is Shown Here</h1>
      </a>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article>
      <a href="#article" title="Article Title">
        <span class="archive-img-wrap"><img class="archive-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/2MAsv6e.jpg" alt="Article Title" /></span>
        <h1 class="archive-title">The Amazing Article Title is Shown Here</h1>
      </a>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article>
      <a href="#article" title="Article Title">
        <span class="archive-img-wrap"><img class="archive-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/2MAsv6e.jpg" alt="Article Title" /></span>
        <h1 class="archive-title">The Amazing Article Title is Shown Here</h1>
      </a>
    </article>
  </li>
</ul>
```